# Multi-Dimensional Array from matching mysql columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have a table with industries and categories as seen below.

```
id|industry|category        |
1 |Building|Air Conditioning|
2 |Building|Roofing         |
3 |Security|Cameras         |
```

I am trying to return an array as follows

```
   array(
    "Building" => array(
        "Air Conditioning",
        "Roofing",
    ),
    "Security" => array(
        "Cameras",
    ),
);
```

What is the best way to approach this.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate once over the data:

```
$data = [
    [1, "Building", "Air Conditioning"],
    [2, "Building", "Roofing"],
    [3, "Security", "Cameras"]
];
$result = [];
foreach ($data as $row) {
    if (!array_key_exists($row[1], $result)) {
        $result[$row[1]] = [];
    }
    array_push($result[$row[1]], $row[2]);
}
var_dump($result);
```

[Link to Fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2d6b334af19ba189d28c393931e0d5a813c8f94a)

Comment: Thanks this was the best response, thanks so much for your knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$query = mysql_query('select * from table');
foreach ($data = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
    $array[$data->industry][] = $data->category;
}

print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$tbl_industries = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'industry' => 'Building',
        'category' => 'Air Conditioning'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'industry' => 'Building',
        'category' => 'Roofing'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'industry' => 'Security',
        'category' => 'Cameras'
    )
);

foreach($tbl_industries as $industry) {
    $industry_name = $industry['industry'];
    $industries[$industry_name][] = $industry['category'];
}

var_dump($industries);
```

**OR**

The code with database interaction:

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'db_name');
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_industries";

if($result = mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
    while($industry = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $industry_name = $industry['industry'];
        $industries[$industry_name][] = $industry['category'];
    }

    mysqli_free_result($result);        
    var_dump($industries);
}
```